# TextBox Value Issue

Tags: javascript, html

I've build a website that read barcode from the camera.
I can catch the barcode text and print it to the P element as you can see below.
But I want to see it in textbox. Is this possible? I can't see the barcode at value of the textbox.

[image]

After press the Scan Barcode button:(5901234123457 is scanned barcode. I want to see it in textbox)
[image]

```
  <p id="code">I see the scanned value here</p>

   <input class="form-control" type="text" id="code" value="Scanned barcode must be seen here...">
   <button  onclick="barkod()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Scan Barcode</button>

    <script>
    function barkod() {
    var resultElement = document.getElementById("code");
    setupLiveReader(resultElement)
    }  
    </script
```

Answer (score 1):

Item IDs must be unique within a single page.

```js
function barkod() {
  document.getElementById("code_copy").value = document.getElementById("code_src").textContent;
  //setupLiveReader(resultElement);
}
```

```html
<p id="code_src">5901234123457</p>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="code_copy" value="Scanned barcode must be seen here...">
<button onclick="barkod()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Scan Barcode</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue you are facing is because you have the same *id attribute* `id="code"` in both the elements, so the `getElementById("code")` returns the first element with the id "code" and thus only that value changes.

Just change the id of the `<p>` tag and add `id="code"` on the input tag

```js
// whatever the value you want
const barcode = 12345566;

document.getElementById("code").value = barcode;
```

```html
 <p id = "para"></p>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="code" value="Scanned barcode must be seen here..." />
```